# Bayes Theorem. If conditional on $\theta$ ,$ X $ and $Y$ are $Normal ( \theta ,1 ) $ then $Y |X$ is $Normal (X,1)$

Tags: self-study, bayesian, inference, conditional-probability

If conditional on $\theta$ ,$ X $  and $Y$ are $Normal (  \theta ,1 ) $ $\theta$ is real ( unknown) and     $f ( y |\theta)$ is the pdf of $y$ and $f ( x |\theta)$ is the pdf of $x$. How can we show that the $Y |X$ is $Normal (x,1)$. In other words find the pdf of $f (y |x)$ ?

I am asumming that , $f (y |x)  = \frac{f(y,x)}{f( x)} $

or $$$$ $f (y |x  \theta ) = \frac{f(y,x|   \theta )}{f( x|  \theta )} =\frac{f(y |   \theta )f(x|   \theta )}{f( x|  \theta )} =f (y |  \theta) $  which is does not make sense.

**Edit Below:**

We know that $f(y|x) = \int   f(y|\theta )  \pi(\theta|x)  d\theta  $, Where $ \pi(\theta|x) $is the posterior pdf of   $\theta $given $X=x $.

we know the form of $f(y|\theta )$ from above.

**We must show** : $f(y|x) = (2π)^{(1/2)} * e^{-(y-x)^2/2} $ which I think it means $Y |X$ is $Normal (X,1)$

$f(y|x)$ is called posterior predictive probability density function.

Comment: It will be difficult to prove this since it is not true. It *is* true if $\theta$ has a flat prior on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and the conditional is interpreted as being after $\theta$ is marginalized out. If $\theta$ is interpreted as fixed then your last result, which “does not make sense” is the correct result - if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then conditioning on $X$ doesn’t do anything.

Comment: The question is missing (i) information about the conditional joint of $(X,Y)$ and (ii) the marginal on $\theta$. Without these two items of information, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: **Edit Below:**


 We know that $f(y|x) = \int   f(y|\theta )  \pi(\theta|x)  d\theta  $, Where $ \pi(\theta|x) $is the posterior pdf of   $\theta $given $X=x $.


we know the form of $f(y|\theta )$ from above.

 **We must show** : $f(y|x) = (2π)^{(1/2)} * e^{-(y-x)^2/2} $ which I think it means $Y |X$ is $Normal (X,1)$

$f(y|x)$ is called posterior predictive probability density function.